# Where is the __add__ method implemented in pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset?

Tags: pandas

For example, if I write

```
bday = pd.tseries.offsets.BusinessDay()
bday + pd.Timestamp('2020-03-03')
```

The addition operator must be implemented somehwere in the `pd.tseries.offsets.BusinessDay` class, but I can't find the implemention in the source code at all. Where can I find it?

Comment: It's from the class [`DateOffset`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/tseries/offsets.py#L156) inherited by `SingleConstructorOffset` < `BusinessDay`

Comment: I looked inside `DateOffset ` but all I see is a some pseudocode in the docstring (lines 181-190), not a full implementation: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.0.1/pandas/tseries/offsets.py#L156-L488

Comment: @ChrisA can you point out to me which line I can find the implementation in the source code?

Comment: apologies, maybe [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/_libs/tslibs/offsets.pyx#L320) actually in class `_BaseOffset` - `__add__` at line 391